# Python cql library not able to update a boolean column using query substitution

Tags: python, cassandra, cql

**Intro**
I'm using the python [cql library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cql/1.0.4) library to access a Cassandra 1.2 database (CQL 3.0). My table contains a boolean column as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE test (
     id         text,
     value      boolean,
     PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

**The problem**
When I try to execute a query like this one using the cql library:

```
UPDATE test set value=True where id = 'someid'
```

And using this code:

```
import cql
...
cql_statement = "UPDATE test set value=:value where id = :id"
rename_dict = {'id':'someid', 
               'value': True}
cursor.execute(cql_statement, rename_dict)
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Bad Request: Invalid STRING constant (True) for value of type boolean
```

Seems like the cql library is trying to execute this:

```
UPDATE test set value='True' where id = 'someid'
```

Instead of this:

```
UPDATE test set value=True where id = 'someid'
```

**The question**

Is there any workaround for this or better way/library to use? (I'm using Cassandra 1.2 with CQL 3.0 CFs, so pycassa is not an option)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your ID type should be an integer rather than a string.  Also, are you using CQL driver version 1.0.4 that you link to, or the latest (1.4.0)?

Comment: Hi Richard, I'm using the latest (1.4.0). Can you elaborate about not using a string as a key please?

Comment: id is an int in your table definition but you are setting it to the string 'someid'.

Comment: Thank you so much Richard, I edited the question to fix it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Boolean quoting [has been fixed in the upstream](https://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/cassandra-dbapi2/source/detail?r=38ed5babd81889e6879d44a3d43928009d2447b9&path=/cql/query.py) since this question was asked, though Debian packages are not updated yet.

Thus solution is to install the library from source.